# Quando chamo python manage.py migrate da esse probleminha e por causa do pycham?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Python e Django]

Quando estou para testar o banco de dados (SQLite3) sempre dá esse mesmo erro.
lembrando que não estou usando um banco de dados para produção, pois, esse sistema é só para treinar mesmo.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: já tentou instalar o módulo `start_Django` como informado na mensagem?